# Ember.js: Registered non-singleton is actually a singleton when injected into a certain view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dependency-injection, singleton, handlebars.js

I want to inject an instance of a certain controller into every instance of a certain view type. The view is rendered/instantiated with:

```
{{view "view-name"}}
```

from within a template. I passed in `{singleton: false}` as options object for `App.register` but the controller is still only instantiated once. How to ensure that every view object gets its very own controller instance? See this jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/geyunize/3

## Update

I realized that it has nothing to do with `{{view}}`. The same thing happens when looking up a view class directly. e.g.

```
App.__container__.lookup("view:injected-slot")
App.__container__.lookup("view:injected-slot")
App.__container__.lookup("view:injected-slot")
```

will create 3 new view instances but the injected `alternatives` instance is always the same.

I found out that when looking up the view, ember will lookup the appropriate view class and then cache it. Only if it is not cached yet, ember will lookup all the injections. So after the view class was looked up for the first time it is cached and won't get looked up again and so won't the injections.

I'm not sure if this is a bug or works as intended.

Comment: did you try using `{{render}}` instead?

Comment: Yes I did. But that did nothing. In fact it has nothing to do with `{{view}}` or `{{render}}`. Because the same thing happens when I just do `App.__container__.lookup("view:injected-slot")` several times.

Comment: ..interesting..i think you better post the question's link in discuss.emberjs.com .. you might get response from direct emberjs guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that it is a confirmed bug. https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/5266